# Backup printers from a faulty drive to USB

Tags: windows-10, backup, batch, printer, export

I trying to backup the printers from a faulty machine which cannot boot up to a external USB. How can go about it ?

I am currently using this command to backup to USB for printers backup:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\Spool\Tools\printbrm.exe -b -f d:\userid_Backup\backup.printerexport
```

Comment: printbrm must be run on the machine that has the printers installed. If that machine can't boot you can't run printbrm.